# Javascript. Expanding a string of numbers

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My script is in a google spreadsheet document
Here is my script:

ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

```
function onOpen() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "10 Rows", functionName: "TenRows"},
                      {name: "20 Rows", functionName: "TwentyRows"},
                      {name: "30 Rows", functionName: "ThirtyRows"},
                      {name: "40 Rows", functionName: "FortyRows"},
                      {name: "50 Rows", functionName: "FiftyRows"}]                      
   ss.addMenu("Insert Rows", menuEntries);
 }


 function TenRows() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(2,10);
 }

 function TwentyRows() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(2,20);
 }

 function ThirtyRows() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(2,30);
 }

 function FortyRows() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(2,40);
 }

 function FiftyRows() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(2,50);
 }
```

In column C of my spreadsheet I have a string of numbers going down each row.

Like this

```
 C
7317
7316
7315
7314
7313
```

​
When I run my script to insert a number of rows, How can I make it so it automatically continues this ascending number and inputs it into the C column?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I obviously can't give you the code without seeing the whole thing, but I can give you advice on how to solve it:

1. Before inserting the new rows, save the number that was in the row after which the new ones will be inserted, into a variable e.g. `lastNumber = parseInt(insertRowColumnC.getValue())` make sure to use `parseInt` to convert the string into a number(!)
2. Insert the new rows
3. Now iterate over all the newly inserted rows from top to bottom
4. On each row you first decrement `lastNumber` by one, and then write it's value into column C on that row

**Update**

After having a look at the spreadsheet I'd spent some minutes and came up with this piece of code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.source.getActiveRange();
  if (r.getColumn() == 3 && r.getRow() == 2) {
    var value = parseInt(r.getValue());
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
      var next = getFirstRowNumber(sheet);
      if (value > next) {
        var count = value - next;
        sheet.insertRowsAfter(2, count);
        for(var i = 2; i < 2 + count; i++) {
          sheet.getRange(i + 1, 3).setValue(value);
          value--;
        }
        r.setValue('');

      } else {
         r.setValue('');
         Browser.msgBox('You need to enter a greater ID.');
      }
    } else if (r.getValue() !== '') {
      r.setValue('');
      Browser.msgBox('You need to enter a valid ID.');
    }
  }
}
```

Your question was a bit unclear, but this works how you want it to.

Whenever some inserts a new ID in 2/C, the missing IDs bewteen the new ID and the ID in 3/C are inserted automatically.

Comment: Ivo, Is there anyway I could share the document with you. I'm not sure I know how to implement this.